# Angular testing using Jasmine and Karma

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to improve code coverage of Angular app. In code coverage it is mentioned that if else condition is not covered. Could anyone tell me how to do that?
Feel free to ask for more code details.

```
public searchByText(textVal: any): void {
        let matchedEquipments = [];
        // **
        if (this.model.searchText.length > 1) {
            matchedEquipments = this.refineByText(textVal, this.equipments);
        } else {
            matchedEquipments = this.equipments;
        }
        // **
        matchedEquipments = this.refineByPlant(this.model.plants, matchedEquipments);
        matchedEquipments = this.refineByPlantIsland(this.model.plantIslands, matchedEquipments);
        matchedEquipments = this.refineByProcess(this.model.processes, matchedEquipments);
        matchedEquipments = this.refineByIndustry(this.model.divisions, matchedEquipments);
        this.displayClientData(matchedEquipments);
        this.updateSearchCounters(SelectionFilter.FreeText);
}
```

Spec:

```
it('verify the result with search', async(() => {
        equipmentSelectionComponent.searchByText("123");
        //equipmentSelectionComponent.model.searchText = "123";
        expect(equipmentSelectionComponent.matchedData.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
}));
```

Comment: `.searchByText("")`?

Comment: its a method name of component

Comment: No, I mean that's how you can test the other case. Look at the condition, think about the possible routes through your logic.

Comment: can i write one case with condition success and one for else?

Comment: Yes, you should have at least one test for each case.

Comment: it('verify the result with search with condition true', async(() => {
        equipmentSelectionComponent.searchByText("123");
        //equipmentSelectionComponent.model.searchText = "123";
        expect(equipmentSelectionComponent.matchedData.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
}));

it('verify the result with search with condition false', async(() => {
        equipmentSelectionComponent.searchByText("123");
        equipmentSelectionComponent.model.searchText = "123";
        expect(equipmentSelectionComponent.matchedData.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
}));
but its not working

Comment: Then [edit] the question to give a [mre]. What does *"not working"* mean, exactly? Note you seem to have the same test twice, which isn't going to improve your coverage.

Comment: @SuruchiBabbar : Did my answer helped ? Please mark it as an answer if it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need write more than just 1 `it` block to test this:

```
it('should call "refineByText" when search Text is there', async(() => {
   spyOn(equipmentSelectionComponent,'refineByText').and.callThrough();
   equipmentSelectionComponent.model.searchText = "some Val";
   equipmentSelectionComponent.equipments = ["item1"]
   equipmentSelectionComponent.searchByText("123");
   expect(equipmentSelectionComponent.refineByText).toHaveBeenCalledWith("123",["item1"]); // <-- this will check true condition
   // I dont see "matchedData" in your provided code so I dont know about this check.
   expect(equipmentSelectionComponent.matchedData.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
   // spy and check other function calls as well just like I did for refineByText
}));

it('should not call "refineByText" when search Text is empty', async(() => {
   spyOn(equipmentSelectionComponent,'refineByText').and.callThrough();
   equipmentSelectionComponent.model.searchText = "";
   equipmentSelectionComponent.searchByText("123");
   expect(equipmentSelectionComponent.refineByText).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // <-- this will check true condition
   // similarly use use "toHaveBeenCalledWith(val) for other functions
}));
```

I wouold recommend you to read [testing with spies](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49) and also [some more basic testing ways](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-basic-html-elements-using-karma-jasmine-in-angular-fd5e4ac62d78?source=---------15------------------) of angular. This would help you to get more familiar with unit testing mindset. Feel free to clap as well  !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Below test cases should be able to include the coverage for your test case

1. if condition : should assign to matchedEquipments by modifying the equipments when searchText has value

   Expectation :

   ```
    refineByText toHaveBeenCalledWith(textVal, this.equipments)
   ```
2. else condition : should assign equipment to matchedEquipments  when searchText has no value

   Expectation :

   ```
    refineByText not.toHaveBeenCalledWith(textVal, this.equipments)
   ```